# Multiple Jquery Version for extension reason

Tags: magento-1.9, css, ajax, jquery

I get some issue my custom theme and it's get from one of extension jquery version.
How can I fix this issue ?

extension .xml file;

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/iyzicoonpagecheckoutform/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</name><params/></action>
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <script type="text/javascript">izQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
                    ]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
```

And local.xml file in my custom theme ;

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <!--input js-->
        <action method="addJs"><script>smartwave/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>smartwave/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js</script></action>
```

I don't have any issue my custom theme version , everything get about extension jquery version.But I don't know how to fix is ?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I'd recommend do not break any values in XML file

```
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">izQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>]]></text>
```

Make your code more obvious. For that purpose better put `noConflict` function into separate file. And include it as you included jQuery lib.

In conclusion there are much more possible answers. Better show us which error did you face.